# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Deploy and set/update environment variables dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to set/update an environment variable on the EC2 instance after the application is deployed.

Essentially, I want to set a environment variable of lets say `APP_NAME`

and then in php, I would call that variable with `$_SERVER['APP_NAME']`.

The dynamic part would be on deploy of CodeCommit application, it creates the app name `"VersionLabel=>app-a1ee-190913_152539"` as an example. So I would like `APP_NAME`=`app-a1ee-190913_152539`.

I am not using docker, I am merely using Git with CodeCommit and then EB CLI to deploy to my Elastic Beanstalk application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eb CLI you can use the `setenv` command

e.g.

```
eb setenv APP_NAME=app-a1ee-190913_152539
```

See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html) for more details.

Comment: Hello ubi, thank you for your reply. Yes, I could do that for each time I deploy to an environment but I was trying to do it dynamically so that when I do `eb deploy Production` it would create the app name such as `app-a1ee-190913_152539` on it's own and then at the same time, the environment would grab that new app name and update the variable to that name. I am exploding the app name and grabbing just the `190913_152539` part of it and setting that as a version control for css and js files so that I do not have to set the version control myself manually each time I deploy code to a server.